# Spawning enemy waves in formation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am building a space shooter game and so far I can spawn the enemies using waypoints, but I can't make them stay on the screen next to each other. I want to spawn the enemies in formation. Can someone give me an advice on how to do that, similar to the picture?

[image: Example of what I want]

Comment: Please post your code, and show which part does not work as expected.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, that's why I am asking an advice. The code is for the enemies to follow the waypoints and that is it. I want to make them stop next to eachother, not overlap on the last waypoint.

Comment: Then you'll have to create mulitple waypoints (formation).

Comment: So for each object separate waypoint? Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way would be to take a vector point, give it an offset(left/right/up/down) and spawn another object there.
Ex: Enemy1 spawns at (0,0,0) then enemy 2 must spawn at enemy1.transform.position+new v3(0,0,5)- something like that. if u have fixed offsets, just set it for one enemyobject and others will fall into pplace.

Comment: That could work, I will try it. Thanks for the answer.